# How to add HTML below login button?

Tags: php, wordpress

This example of the [`login_form`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form) action reference adds a note or bit of text below the password box:

```
add_action( 'login_form', 'login_extra_note' );

function login_extra_note() {

    //Adding the text

    ?>
    <p>You can type a little note to those logging in here.</p>

    <?php
}
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I add the node below the login button? The result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you [view the source for where this hook is defined](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-login.php#L880), you'll notice that there isn't a hook for what you're looking for.

As a result, you're going to need to either hack the appearance with CSS or JS, or (recommended instead) [build a custom login form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page) using `wp_login_form();`